# Create CSV list of all products & their categories

Tags: magento-1.7, product, category

can somebody suggest me a way or **a script to export a csv file with all product SKUs & the categories** those SKUs are associated to?

I've tried several things... but nothing seems to work. Magento's product export isn't working for me.. It gives me errors.

1. I've tried the Aten's script [[source code]](https://www.atensoftware.com/p188.php) but it prints the
   categories in json format..
2. so i've also tried this:

   ```
   define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
   require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
   Mage::app();

   $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

   $ids = $category->getCollection()->getAllIds();

   if ($ids) {
       $file = "var/import/catwithid.csv";
       file_put_contents($file,"category_ids, sku" . "\n");
       foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
         $string = $id . ', ' . $category->load($id) . "\n";
           file_put_contents($file, $string, FILE_APPEND);
       }
   }
   ```

and this

```
define('MAGENTOROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(MAGENTOROOT.'/app/Mage.php');
umask(0); 
Mage::app('default');

$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
$products->load();

$fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("sku", "category_ids");
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader, $delimiter = ", ");

foreach( $products as $_product ) {
$sku = $_product->getData('sku');
$product = $_product->load($sku);
$product_row = array($sku);
fputcsv( $fp, $product_row, $delimiter = ", ");
}
```

I've also tried to merge them together but with no luck! :/

please help me!!

Comment: What sort of errors do you have with generic export?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//optional for only enabled products
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);//optional for products only visible in catalog and search
$fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("sku", "category_ids");
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");
foreach ($products as $product){
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $categoryIds = implode('|', $product->getCategoryIds());//change the category separator if needed
    fputcsv($fp, array($sku, $categoryIds), ",");
}
fclose($fp);
```

put the script in a file on the same level as `index.php` and run it in the browser or command line.

Comment: yes, it worked! thank you very much you!! :)

Comment: @Marius If I want the categories names instead of categories ids?

Comment: @Muk. Then you can load each category based on the id and get its name. `foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $id){$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id); $name = $category->getName()}`.  You can even remember the loaded categories in an array to avoid loading the same category twice for performance.

Comment: Varien_File_Csv

Comment: What's an easy way to download every attribute using this method? @Marius