# Export Magento 1.8 category list with product name and sku

Tags: export, category-products

I'm looking at the post here:

[Create CSV list of all products & their categories](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5897/create-csv-list-of-all-products-their-categories)

and the instructions to "put the script in a file on the same level as index.php and run it in the browser or command line."

I'm new to Magento. Does this mean to create a .bat file and place it in same file level as index.php?  Where is index.php located?

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the script tells you what kind of file it is: a .php file. So you'll need to use a text-editor to create that file, give it any name you like, and make sure you save it with a .php extension.

As to the location of your index.php file, it is located at your document root for your website, typically a folder called public_html or www or something similar.

After you create the file you will need to upload it to your server and call it from your browser:

www.yourdomain.com/yourscript.php

This will cause the server to execute that file and perform whatever actions you have included in it.

This is really basic stuff. If any of it is making you nervous or perhaps ask more questions than you have, please consider hiring a developer to assist you.